# Resource can't be accessed if class in subdirectory

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a java FX application and depending on the path of a .java file, a resource from the resource folder can or cannot be loaded. (I dont think this issue is java FX related btw).

This is my project strucure:

```
java/com/example/app/
-File1.java
-subdirectory/
    -File2.java
resources/com/example/views/
-View1.fxml
-View2.fxml
```

In File1, by using the following line of code to load the resource, the file loads successfully.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Views/View1.fxml"));
```

However, in File2 the resource can't be located.

If I move File2 to the parent directory I does work, but is not the solution I'm looking for.

Can someone explain why? Thx

Comment: I'm surprised `"views/View1.fxml"` works in either class, assuming that project structure is accurate. Both classes should require you use `"/com/example/views/View1.fxml"`. That said, reading [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627) may help.

Comment: You should respect case when using resources, for example `Views/View1.fxml` should be `views/View1.fxml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

The reason is that you are passing a `relative file path` as argument, instead of an `absolute file path`. This is not recommended.

Your path should look like this:

```
String fxmlPath="/com/example/views/View1.fxml";
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
```

**Note:**

If you are using IntelliJ and you write the first `/` of your path, you can press `CTRL+SPACE` to autocomplete your path from here on. Maybe this works in other IDEs too.

Comment: This works thanks, but to which directory is the relative path on File2 pointing at? Is there a way to check it?

Comment: The root of a relative path points to the directory of the file it is created in. If you create a relative path in File2.java, the root is "subdirectory/". Just a note: All paths starting with a "/" are absolute, all other paths are relative. The knowledge about paths is absolutely necessary for developers, you really need to work that up, because you won't get happy without that! Additional topic: Filesystempath vs classpath. And both can be relative or absolute. :)

Comment: @Carlosz For `getClass().getResource("<relativePath>")`, the path is relative to the location of the class.  That will be defined by the package the class is in (which could change if you copy this code to another class in another package).  Usually, I look resources up relative to my application class, (e.g. `MyApplication.class.getResource()`) because it is easier for me to know where to place and how to find the resource.  Ensure you don't use `..` to find relative resources in a parent folder, that will work with a file system resource but not a jar-packaged resource.